# Extracting string from char array specified by prefix and suffix

Tags: c

I want to write a function which extracts data from char array, which contains data specified by prefix (e.g. `"type="`) and suffix (e.g. `","`). I have hard time working with `strstr` and pointer arythmetics, so I think posting my attempts to write that function is pointless. I want body of function to look like this:

```
void extract_string(char input[], char output[], char start[], end[]) {
    ...
}
```

and call of function (with parameters) to look like this:

```
// extracting type and nickname
char message[128] = "type=client_information,port=6666,hostname=127.0.0.1,nickname=stack,";
char type[32];
char nickname[32];
extract_string(message, type, "type=", ",");
extract_string(message, nickname, "nickname=", ",");
```

Can you please show me correct way to implement this function? It think this is not too complicated, I just stuck somewhere... Thank you for your concern.

Comment: "I think posting my attempts to write that function is pointless" <-- No it is not. Show code and attempts to debug and specific question.

Comment: _"I just stuck somewhere"_ Where? What did you have trouble with? I'm not sure there's really a question here.

Comment: We cannot tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't show it to us.

Comment: do you want the extracted string to include the prefix and postfix?

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. assumes that the 'output[]' array is long enough to hold the result+1
2. assumes that the 'output[]' is not to include the strings 'start[]' nor 'end[]'

Caveat: this is not tested

Caveat: the resulting char array in 'output[]' is not NUL terminated so the calling code (probably) should pre initialize that array to all '\0'

```
void extract_string(char input[], char output[], char start[], end[])
{
    char *startPos = strstr( input, start );
    if( !startPos )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, " %s not found in %s\n", start, input );
        return;
    }

    startPos += strlen( start );

    char *stopPos = strstr( startPos, end );
    if( !stopPos )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, " %s not found in %s\n", end, startPos );
        return;
    }

    memcpy( output, startPos, stopPos - startPos +1 );
} // end function: extract_string
```